# Android - load data from email - works on one device, not another

Tags: android, email, android-intent, attachment

I am trying to load a configuration file sent by email.

My original development device, a lenovo A1 will read it perfectly but when I try on anything else I either don't get a button or I get the message "No applications can perform this action"

I have been trying various versions of android manifest including

```
<activity android:name=".ConfigurationActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:mimeType="application/jcrlccip" android:scheme="content"></data>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

and

```
<activity android:name=".ConfigurationActivity" 
android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
<intent-filter
        android:label="Comfort Android Data"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.jcrlccip" android:scheme="content"></data>
    <data android:mimeType="application/jcrlccip" 
        android:scheme="content"></data>
    <data android:path="*.jcrlccip"></data>
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

but to no effect except on the original device.....

Answer (score 0):

The final answer was.....

```
<activity android:name=".ConfigurationActivity" android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"></action>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"></action>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"></category>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"></category>
        <data android:pathPattern="*.jcrlccip"></data>
        <data android:mimeType="application/jcrlccip"></data>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

the pathPattern made all the difference
tried with mimeType=application/octet-stream but without the pathpattern and it offered to open everything but wouldn't actually open anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem here [Downloading attachment from g/email in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225361/downloading-attachment-from-g-email-in-android). I found that I needed different filters to download from different email clients. My app will pick up an attachment from Hotmail but needs a different approach for the same attachment on GMail.