# Downloading attachment from g/email in Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

I want to download custom files from email to my app. I used intent filters below as suggested by Richard Legget. The app works fine in the Eclipse VM and downloads the file, but won't work when installed on Nexus 7 (Kit Kat) or Acer (ICS) tablets. The View button shows up on the email attachment in the VM but not on the real tablets. Any ideas would be appreciated.

```
        </intent-filter>  
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="application/fdh"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.fdh" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="*"
                android:mimeType="application/octet-stream"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.fdh" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Solved it with help from @Sergey. My custom file is in fact XML format so I now save as an xml file and use this:-

```
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

            <data
                android:host="com.mydomain.myapp"
                android:mimeType="text/xml"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.xml" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GMail doesn't let you click URL's with unknown schemes, so you can use the schema that beginning with "http://".
To define in manifest do something like this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="com.yourdomain.yourapp"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: http scheme doesn't work. I need the mimeType application/.. for the email app to recognize my app as able to View the attachment. I can see by debugging in Eclipse that the scheme is "file" and my code checks that. As I said, it works perfectly in the VM but not on a tablet.

Comment: Your application/ scheme will work fine in simulator, but on real device with standard gmail client for mail, it will not work! This is limitation of gmail client not trouble in your code.

Comment: Solved with changes shown above. Many thanks @Sergey.

Comment: Interestingly, my original intent-filter will work for files sent or received in a Hotmail account but not GMail which requires the modified filter.

Comment: Yes! This is limitation of gmail client. Another mail client may support custom schemas.